# No sound in my ubuntu system 18.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

One day ago, my system had absolutely fine sound and the microphone was working fine. However, now there is no system sound and when I enable my earbuds with the system, I can hear the system sound but on a Zoom call, I can't communicate because I can only hear others.
I have tried various solutions but nothing has worked. Could you please help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEmXw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyfun.png)

Answer (score 0):

On the above image, in your Sound Settings the sound device is shown as **Dummy Output** which means that *your sound card is not recognised!*

To fix the issue, you can try force reloading [ALSA](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture)

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

If it still doesn't work try attempting a re-install of the below two packages

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio
```

and then

```
sudo alsa force-reload

pulseaudio --start
```